# Generating complex sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I currently have an employee logging sql table that has 3 columns

`fromState: String`, 
`toState: String`, 
`timestamp: DateTime`

`fromState` is either `In` or `Out`.  `In` means employee came in and `Out` means employee went out.  Each row can only transition from `In` to `Out` or `Out` to `In`.

I'd like to generate a temporary table in sql to keep track during a given hour (hour by hour), how many employees are there in the company.  Aka, resulting table has columns `HourBucket`, `NumEmployees`.

In non-SQL code I can do this by initializing the `numEmployees` as `0` and go through the table row by row (sorted by `timestamp`) and add (employee came in) or subtract (went out) to `numEmployees` (bucketed by `timestamp` hour).

I'm clueless as how to do this in SQL.  Any clues?

Comment: You should check, then double check, then triple check that the "in"s and "out"s are correct.  Does an employee ever have two "in"s or two "out"s in a row?  Is there always a matching pair?

Comment: no, that's not an issue.  It's definitely the way I stated, I just don't know how to do it in SQL.

Comment: I guess you know that because there is also (at least) a fourth column with the employee id !?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the number "in" will always return to zero overnight? If not, I don't see how you'll get the number without summing across the entire table every time.

Comment: I don't really understand why you store both a from state and a to state. Wouldn't one or the other suffice?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use a `COUNT ... GROUP BY` query. Can't see what you're using toState from your description though! Also, assuming you have an employeeID field.

E.g.

```
SELECT fromState AS 'Status', COUNT(*) AS 'Number' 
FROM StaffinBuildingTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT employeeID AS 'empID', MAX(timestamp) AS 'latest' FROM StaffinBuildingTable GROUP BY employeeID) AS LastEntry ON StaffinBuildingTable.employeeID = LastEntry.empID
GROUP BY fromState
```

The LastEntry subquery will produce a list of employeeIDs limited to the last timestamp for each employee.

The INNER JOIN will limit the main table to just the employeeIDs that match both sides.

The outer GROUP BY produces the count.

```
SELECT HOUR(SBT.timestamp) AS 'Hour', SBT.fromState AS 'Status', COUNT(*) AS 'Number' 
FROM StaffinBuildingTable AS SBT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SBIJ.employeeID AS 'empID', MAX(timestamp) AS 'latest' 
    FROM StaffinBuildingTable AS SBIJ
    WHERE DATE(SBIJ.timestamp) = CURDATE()
    GROUP BY SBIJ.employeeID) AS LastEntry ON SBT.employeeID = LastEntry.empID
GROUP BY SBT.fromState, HOUR(SBT.timestamp)
```

Replace CURDATE() with whatever date you are interested in.

Note this is non-optimal as it calculates the HOUR twice - once for the data and once for the group.

Again you are using the INNER JOIN to limit the number of returned row, this time to the last timestamp on a given day.

Comment: I recognize I didn't explain the question appropriately.  I would like to have a resulting TABLE where the columns are `HourBucket` and `NumEmployees`.  Each row represents the number of employees at that given hour bucket.

Answer (score 0):

To me your description of the `FromState` and `ToState` seem the wrong way round, I'd expect to doing this based on the `ToState`. But assuming I'm wrong on that the following should point you in the right direction:

First, I create a "Numbers" table containing 24 rows one for each hour of the day:

```
create table tblHours
(Number int);

insert into tblHours values
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),
(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),
(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);
```

Then for each date in your employee logging table, I create a row in another new table to contain your counts:

```
create table tblDailyHours
(
HourBucket datetime,
NumEmployees int
);

insert into tblDailyHours (HourBucket, NumEmployees)
select distinct
    date_add(date(t.timeStamp), interval h.Number HOUR) as HourBucket,
    0 as NumEmployees
from 
tblEmployeeLogging t
CROSS JOIN tblHours h;
```

Then I update this table to contain all the relevant counts:

```
update tblDailyHours h
    join
    (select
        h2.HourBucket,
        sum(case when el.fromState = 'In' then 1 else -1 end) as cnt
     from
        tblDailyHours h2
        join tblEmployeeLogging el on
            h2.HourBucket >= el.timeStamp
     group by h2.HourBucket
    ) cnt ON
    h.HourBucket = cnt.HourBucket
set NumEmployees = cnt.cnt;
```

You can now retrieve the counts with

```
select * 
from tblDailyHours
order by HourBucket;
```

The counts give the number on site *at* each of the times displayed, if you want *during* the hour in question, we'd need to tweak this a little.

There is a working version of this code (using not very realistic data in the logging table) here: [rextester.com/DYOR23344](http://rextester.com/DYOR23344)

**Original Answer** (Based on a single over all count)

If you're happy to search over all rows, and want the current "head count" you can use this:

```
select
    sum(case when t.FromState = 'In' then 1 else -1) as Heads
from
    MyTable t
```

But if you know that there will always be no-one there at midnight, you can add a where clause to prevent it looking at more rows than it needs to:

```
where
    date(t.timestamp) = curdate()
```

Again, on the assumption that the head count reaches zero at midnight, you can generalise that method to get a headcount at any time as follows:

```
where
    date(t.timestamp) = "CENSUS DATE" AND
    t.timestamp <= "CENSUS DATETIME"
```

Obviously you'd need to replace my quoted strings with code which returned the date and datetime of interest. If the headcount doesn't return to zero at midnight, you can achieve the same by removing the first line of the `where` clause.

Comment: Looking at your question again, I'm not too sure this is really what you want. You're after a count PER HOUR. Of just "today"?

Comment: I recognize I didn't explain it quite well.  I would like a hour by hour of the # of employees at the company.

Comment: No worries, I need to get to bed, but will revisit tomorrow and attempt an answer if no-one did in the meantime. Is it just "today" you want or all hours since anything was logged in the table? or something between? Also does the building empty overnight? If so the code can be more efficient with a where clause as per my original answer.

Comment: I would like to have a resulting TABLE where the columns are `HourBucket` and `NumEmployees`.  Each row represents a particular hour say 2014-05-22T22:00:00 and a count of number of employees for that hour.

Comment: Okay, I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: I've just edited this to reflect the clarified question. There may be more efficient approaches, but this looks like it would work.